# Get Weekly SUM from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get a list of mysql results for each week beginning at July 2015, showing the SUM or new users from my table user GROUPED BY Week. Is this possible?

So as result:

```
CW25/15: 100
CW26/15: 70
CW27/15: 180
....
```

How to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this(You didn't post your table structures so you will have to adjust it) :

```
SELECT concat('CW',week(DateColumn),'/',year(DateColumn)) as weekDate,
       count(*) as cnt
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY concat('CW',week(DateColumn),'/',year(DateColumn))
ORDER BY year(DateColumn),week(DateColumn)
```

Comment: Nice, can we do an Order BY Date ASC as well?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('CW',WEEK(date_col),'/',YEAR(date_col)) as week,
       COUNT(*) as count
FROM table_name
GROUP BY YEAR(date_col),WEEK(date_col)
ORDER BY date_col
```